# Failed to connect to JMX while started to use the JMX authentication on Linux

Tags: java, linux, authentication, jmx

My JMX client failed to connect to JMX server while I have started to use the JMX authentication.
I use Java 8 and Centos6.

I have configured the following settings:

```
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=<path to password file> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=<path to access file>"
```

Unfortunately my JMX client failed to connect to JMX server with the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:369)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.jmx.JMXAccessorTask.createJMXConnection(JMXAccessorTask.java:384)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.jmx.JMXAccessorTask.accessJMXConnection(JMXAccessorTask.java:439)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.jmx.JMXAccessorTask.getJMXConnection(JMXAccessorTask.java:477)
        at org.apache.catalina.ant.jmx.JMXAccessorTask.execute(JMXAccessorTask.java:345)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:122)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:205)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1957)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1924)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:287)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:118)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it I read carefully the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#gdeup

The following comment about the password file is very important:

```
You must ensure that only the owner has read and write permissions on this file, since it contains the passwords in clear text. For security reasons, the system checks that the file is only readable by the owner and exits with an error if it is not.
```

I set read permission to a user and my client successfully connects to the JMX server:

```
chmod 400 <path to password file>
```